# What is the turn-on and turn-off condition of the npn-transistor?

Tags: voltage, transistors, current, switching

Following is the circuit I have been analyzing. My intention is to calculate the turn on and off condition of the [transistor](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/308/DTC114E-D-346514.pdf) Q1. R1 and R2 (10 kΩ each) are internal to the transistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBVxkc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Following is my understanding, whenever there is voltage at the input V1, it will equally divide across R1 and R2. When it reaches 0.7 at Vbe, Q1 will be turned on. If I want to increase the turn on voltage of the transistor, introducing voltage divider at the input (before resistor R1) will be sufficient.

I want to on and off the transistor above to a fixed voltage, say 5 V. Please advise my understanding.

Comment: I'm confused. The BJT you reference is a digital BJT with both \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ internalized within the device, already. (A fact you added to the schematic, but which may not be clear to readers of your question.) This BJT is designed for ON/OFF use, which means the collector is intended to be either "high impedance" or else "acting like a voltage source very close in value to the emitter voltage." When you mention \$5\:\text{V}\$ in the text, what exactly is that referring to? Where in the schematic is it expected?

Comment: My aim was to control the bjt on and off for particular user defined input voltage. Just for explanation purpose I took it as 5 V.

Comment: This digital switch must be designed for worst case.  Ice=100uA OFF @Vce=5V and Ib is not specified but could be as high as 33uA with 10% of hFE being 30 or much lower for Ib

Comment: @vt673 But how steep do you expect the transition to be? Tony EE rocketscientist provided a nice simulation that shows that it won’t be steep with such a simple circuit.

Comment: You should probably use a comparator and voltage reference instead of a single transistor.

Comment: Transistors are logarithmic responders, in that the base-emitter voltage is the log of the collector current. Every 0.058 volts of base voltage should cause another 10:1 more collector current. Thus "off" is an uncertain point, until you take the input voltage to ZERO volts. Even at 0.6 volts input, or 0.3 volts on the base, you'll have nanoAmperes of collector current. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This makes a lousy comparator R1/R2 0.8min 1.0typ 1.2max**

Thus +/-20% of 0.6V becomes 20% of 5V is best case and Leakage current affects R3
**Ambient temperature variation adds another 10%.**

---

### General design not for this Q1

- Assuming hFE=100 (bad assumption) and Vce=Vce(sat)  = 0.2V at 10% of hFE or Ic:Ib=10:1
- Ic=15.8V/0.1MΩ = 158uA, Ib=16uA

  - At high temp Leakage current can be 20uA edge of graph not spec'd

  **- so 100k load is a poor choice for this Q1 and hFE can be as low as 30**
- if Vin =5V and Vbe=0.6 ( not 0.7 at this low current)
- Rb=4.4V/16uA=275k
- Next the threshold for turn-on needs to be 5V input.

  - thus 0.6V/5V= 12%
  - thus adding external R1 to internal  **R1= 75k-10k= 48k or **external R1' ~65k**

Threshold at room temp may be 4.4 to 5.7V for 80% output swing.  Simulated with triangle wave.
[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fojoQr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### Suggestion

Define Cost limit, Ambient range, V threshold tolerance and go back to drawing board

Comment: Rb will include internal 10 kΩ resistor too, right?

Comment: If V1 is a 5V voltage source, R1=275k and R2 is not needed.  But if PNP open collector then a pull down is needed.  Or you can make the threshold symmetrical with a Thevenin equivalent divider

Comment: I think you have forgotten the R2 resistor that adds \$60 \rm \mu A\$ to the calculated \$I_B\$.

Comment: You didn't bother to look at the datasheet, did you?

Comment: you guessed correct

Comment: @ElliotAlderson  hFE of 15 at 1mA and his design is Ic=158uA  not good

Comment: I'd like to see whoever did -1 do a worst case tolerance analysis at Ic<1mA over temp on Vin tolerance for Vout = TBD  Much Better to use a Schmitt trigger even CMOS SCh Inv

Comment: hFE =10 http://tinyurl.com/yb98rhts

Comment: After OP defines specs properly for Min max input and output tolerances. External Rext may be from 30k to 65k depending on my expectations for mean threshold and min max  http://tinyurl.com/yd896o5x

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75, how is this 75 kΩ came from? ( R1 = 75 kΩ -10 kΩ)

Comment: Read again. under General Design, if load must be 100k and threshold of 5V +-20% if 75k is 0, threshold is 1.2V

Answer (score 1):

No need for a second voltage divider before the first; you just need to add a second resistor in series with R1. Anyway, beware that the “switching” of a transistor in not ideal. Don’t expect it to behave like an open switch at \$4.9 \rm V\$ and as as closed one at \$5.1 \rm V\$.

Comment: But on voltage is shown as 2.5 V in the datasheet.!! (Page-4)

Comment: I just had a look at the datasheet. There is a “typical” on voltage of \$1.8 V\$ with a “minimum” of \$2.5 V\$‽ They must have messed minimum and maximum values…

Comment: The number in the datasheet is the **maximum** input voltage required to produce a given output current. Note that the **typical** voltage is only 1.8V. According to the datasheet the transistor could be ON for any voltage greater than 0.8V (the minimum OFF voltage), but it is guaranteed to be ON for voltages greater than 2.5V.

Comment: Hence, you can only be sure that the “switching” happens between \$0.8 V\$ and \$2.5 V\$ and, *if you are lucky*, it should happen between \$1.2 V\$ and \$1.8 V\$.

Comment: Can I use zener diode at 5.1 V at the input to confirm the switching?

Comment: @vt673 I don’t understand how/where you would like to use a zener.

Comment: Sorry that was an oversight from my end :-(

Comment: you & OP forgot to look at hFE at Ic< 1mA and leakage current  and Ic rating for Vin Min max

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist If “you” is me, where did I forget them? I did not provide any calculation!

Comment: Look at worst case Ic and hFE for 100uA . It's only 13 at 1mA and dropping to unspecified zone  and factor 10% of linear hFE when saturated. So load ought to be closer to 1mA or 16k not 100k then define an output threshold and margin.  Calculations are tricky but I showed the basic method that works with wide tolerances on Vbe about 0.6V and hFE

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I agree with your calculation (just in case, I did not downvote your answer), but you seem to disagree with mine and I don’t understand where…

Comment: You did not define upper and lower Thresholds for input or output.  This design has a threshold of 1.1V with a gain of ~ 30 and MUST switch at Vin=5V but MAY switch at 0.8V http://tinyurl.com/yd896o5x  Always start with these design parameters for any switch.